# Selecting various date ranges from dataframe in for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a LinearRegression Model working in Python based on TimeSeries dataframe, but want to build a function to backtest the model with an expanding time window.

I've got an initial starting date saved as a variable:

```
df_test_date = datetime(2018,1,1)
```

I then created the first `df_train`

```
df_train = df[df['date'] < df_test_date]
```

And created a mask for the `df_test`

```
mask = (df['date'] > df_test_date) & (df['date'] < (df_test_date + timedelta(days=1)))
df_test = df[mask]
```

Essentially I'd like to then loop through the train and test dataframes by 1 day each time i.e. train on dataframe and test on test day, then train on dataframe plus extra days results and test on test day + 1.

I'd expect that I can include my train, fit and predict models within the for loop and then print results such as accuracy, score etc.